# MVC4: SQL Login failed. Error code 1. Only happening on one page

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have just come across what has to be one of the weirdest (and most frustrating) errors ever. I have a site which has just been put onto a staging server (not yet live). Everything seems to be working fine except one particular page. There is a method being called which invokes a stored procedure, but I am getting a `SqlException` which says `Login failed for [the-login-name]` and an error state of 1. The curious thing is that the exact same method is being called from another page and is using the exact same sql connection details and it's fine.. moreover.. this is ONLY happening on the staging server.. not on my dev machine. Has anyone here ever seen anything like this before? I can't quite figure out what could be different between the 2 that would cause this.

We've all seen the `it works on my dev machine` problem.. but I have never seen where 2 pages calling the same method causes only one of them to throw an exception.. that's just plain freaky.

I am using MVC4 and SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Can you post some code examples of the working page and the non-working page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind;

The place where I am connecting looks like this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
```

context.Database is of `System.Data.Entity.Database` and I just noticed something in the `System.Data.Entity.Database.Connection.ConnectionString`..; on some occasions it has the password in there and other occasions it doesn't. I can't quite figure that one out, but I know what to do now.. I hope this helps others who find this.

Comment: Matt, did you ever find an actual resolution to this?

Comment: Sorry, but this was 7 years ago.. I cannot remember. I only wish my answer here had been more elaborate. If you manage to find the answer, feel free to add it here for anyone else who may stumble across this same problem. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Does the account have enough authorization to run stored procs? Do you have full administrative control of the instance?

If not, you'll need to:

1. Get full admin access; and/or
2. Create a RunStoredProc role, adding to your SQL Account User, and granting to select stored procs.